# VS2010 C# missing project dll during build

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, build

I have problem with build in VS2010. I´m trying to develop small Prism, MVVM application.

I added new project "Toolbar" to my solution "MyApp" and during the build I get following error (propably project´s dll is not created for some reason):

> Error 2   Could not load referenced assembly
> "C:\net\projects\MyApp\MyApp.Modules.Toolbar\bin\Debug\MyApp.Modules.Toolbar.dll".
>
> Caught a FileNotFoundException saying "Could not load file or assembly
> 'C:\net\projects\MyApp\MyApp.Modules.Toolbar\bin\Debug\MyApp.Modules.Toolbar.dll'
> or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file
> specified.".
>
> C:\net\projects\MyApp\MyApp\ResGen    MyApp

I´m quite new to VS2010 and C# so I really don´t know what happend, wheter project dll is missing because of some mistake in source code or why this can even happend? I also don´t know how to find such a mistake in source code, because VS shows up only the error mentioned above. Dependenies of the project should be ok i guess, file MyApp.Modules.Toolbar.dll really doesn´t exist in any folder on my hdd.

Comment: I've seen the error 'Could not load assembly or one of its dependencies' before and it says FileNotFound , but it was in fact due to a mismatch in the platforms they were compiled for (a 32bit environment trying to load a 64bit dll), when building .dlls it's usually best to select Any CPU for the target platform. Just something to be aware of.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was the bad class name defined in xaml of Toolbar project (UserControl x:Class="BAD CLASS HERE").

Answer (score 1):

After many googles for a similar problem where I had at one time toyed with using open office in a .net project and then all my aspx pages had the blue squiggely line saying cli_uno couldn't be found which was referenced no where and in none of my project or lib files.

I deleted all the bin folders, a dll referencing it was hiding in one of them and making vs2010 freak out.

I realize this isn't the exact solution to the above but there isn't much out there for this error and it is a head scratcher and deleting all the bin folders worked for me so it's something to try.

Answer (score 0):

You provide too litle information, so I'll ask some questions (and some possible fixes):

1. Is the file at the specified path to begin with?
2. If not, is there a project you need to build to create the dll?
3. If there is such project, does it build the .dll where yours is looking for it -- if not, you either need to copy it by hand or set up a post-build process to do the copy automatically after each build
4. If there is no such project, do you have the .dll itself somewhere.  If yes, you need to copy it to the correct location.
5. If the .dll is at the correct location, is there some protection preventing the other project to access it?

Comment: The folder at specified path is empty, there is no file, but the folder exists. Project is there but it doesn´t build that MyApp.Modules.Toolbar.dll at all (it´s not anywhere on my hdd). Thanks.

Comment: Thank you everyone for you effort. I went to bed to refresh and finally I could solve it this morning:) The problem was bad class defined in xaml of Toolbar project (<UserControl x:Class="BAD CLASS HERE"). Is there any way how to be announced about such a mistakes form VS? Because if I have to find out such a things manually then it would be very hard at huge projects.

Comment: @mantonn - I would never have guess that :)  You should write your findings in a proper answer to this question and accept it (it is perfectly OK to do so)